# Reload view crash with 'index 0 beyond bounds for empty array' error

Tags: ios, objective-c, indexing

My app is based on core data using MR.

I have 3 views. The three views are -
a `table view` where I can select an entity, when tapped it open the `second view` with all the relatives data and there I have a button that open the `third view` where the user can modify the data.

My problem is that to open the `second view` I have to pass from the table the row number to get the exact entity to be displayed, and here everything fine.

But if the selected entity is the last one in the table and the user modify some data that remove the last row(for example if change the category attribute of the entity), when I go back my app crash, because the row number relative that I passed from the `first view` doesn't exist anymore in my database.

I hope I explained it well. I know the problem, but I don't have any idea of how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by passing the identifier of the entity instead of the row index. So now in the detail view I get my entity using the identifier instead the index.

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is that to open the second view I have to pass from the table the row number to get the exact entity to be displayed

You should not pass the index into the table, since you know that it can change.

Alternatively, you can pass the managed object itself, or its `objectID` (taking into account that `objectID` is expensive).

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, in the left pane there's a breakpoint section (the one with the shape of an arrow… more or less). Open that section. If you hit the + button in the bottom left corner of that pane you can add an Exceptions Breakpoint. This will store the your app and highlight the section where it's crashing. From there you might be able to solve your problem fairly easily: you only need to understand why you're still trying to access that row, instead of the new index of the object. If you still need help at that point, please post the section of your code that's crashing and any related code of that class.